# The manifold formed by n-dimensional positive definite symmetric matrices is of what dimension?

Tags: manifolds

I know that the dimension of the manifold formed by **n-dimensional symmetric matrices** is $\dfrac {n(n+1)}2$.But the manifold formed by **n-dimensional positive definite symmetric matrices** is of what dimension?Thanks!

Comment: This can be answered by answering the following question: Given a positive definite symmetric matrix $A$ and a neighborhood of $A$ in the space of symmetric matrices, which matrices in the neighborhood are also positive definite? I suggest first looking at the case where $A = I$.